# Ceiling fan with 2 switches with remote

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

Where are the wires I have, I am confuse to where the red from the ceiling goes, nothing in the manuals talk about a red wire.

Right now we have 1 switch controlling the light, and 1 controlling the fan.
We want just one switch controlling both so we can just use the remote for function.

From ceiling: Red, Black, White

From fan: Black, White, Green/Yellow, Blue

From remote module: Yellow, Blue, Black, White

Comment: Where are you on Earth? Also post a picture of wiring diagram (it often is done on plastic of the controller itself). Also please post brand and model of both fan and control

Comment: Southeast United States. Here is an image of the remote controller module https://imgur.com/Wl45SYA   Fan is a Hunter,

Comment: Please include the pic in the original question - edit the post.

Comment: Do you want to control the fan with the remote? Or with the switch? "Both" is not an option.  Also, are there other lights in the room controlled by the switch?  Having lights work when you turn on the switch is a Code requirement, first responders need it to get light so they can do a traich/find victims/see your son is holding a gaming mouse and not a gun.

Answer (score 1):

The remote switches the light and fan off using just a single power source. It doesn't rely on 2 like you had. You don't have any use for the red wire any more nor the switch.